# jquery ajax call forbidden by codeigniter 3 csrf

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

windows 10, codeigniter 3, jquery 3

I am testing the ajax function and I am loading data into a div by using the $.post function and sending to a controller method that reads a file and sends back the contents (I know there are other ways of doing it but this is a test). The ajax call looks like this

```
    var btn = 'a[href="click-help"]'
    $(btn).click(function(){

            $.post(
                base_url+'site/cal_help', 
                function(data){
                    $('.cal-help').html(data);
                });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

You can see that the click button is not a form but a link. This works OK when I have csrf set to false but the console shows the call as forbidden if csrf is enabled. Having researched online, I have tried passing data as follows:

```
    {
                    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
    },
```

but it doesn't help. How can I fix it without setting csrf to false, which I would rather not do in case I want it for other elements in the site?

Answer (score 3):

I'm still working away at this and I've discovered a few more interesting things:

Although you can use the Codeigniter Security class like this:

```
<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>
<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>
```

in a view and these functions work, you are also supposed to be able to use them in a script file eg

```
var hash = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>';
console.log(hash);
```

That seems to work within script tags in a view but if in a separate script.js file the console just shows the code printed out. Why should that happen?

However I dug into js string methods and discovered that the following works to retrieve the hash:

```
//get all cookies
var x = document.cookie;
//search for the csrf cookie name
var posname = x.search('csrf_cookie_name');
//slice out hash itself which is always 32 characters long and these numbers work
var hash = x.slice(posname+17,posname+49);
console.log(hash);
```

Having established a variable equal to the hash, you can add the following data to your ajax call:

```
{
   'csrf_test_name' : hash
},
```

I put all that inside the 'click' function so it finds the latest version of the cookie. So I end up with something like this:

```
var btn = '.btn-cal-help a';
$(btn).click(function(){
    var x = document.cookie;
    var posname = x.search('csrf_cookie_name');
    var hash = x.slice(posname+17,posname+49);
    //console.log(hash);    
        $.post(
            base_url + 'site/cal_help', 
            {
                'csrf_test_name' : hash
            }, 
            function(data){
                $('.cal-help').html(data);
            });
    }
    return false;
});
```

and now that works for me (on my local server - wamp) even though I have 'csrf_regenerate' set to TRUE as well.

Comment: my answer will help you understand how it works, adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I do face the similar problem with a project with CSRF protection enabled in all ajax requests. Then I figure out that it happens because the csrf token Regenerate on every request that will result in forbidden error because token doesn't match. So the solution is turn off CSRF token generation on every request. You can do it by setting to this option in your config.php file.

```
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
```

Please note that when I checked laravel's CSRF token, it doesn't change in all requests. So changing csrf regeneration option to false will not cause any major security issues. Please comment below if above method doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply as this. Get your token and hash for each new request and attach it to your post data

Place something like this in your model/controller

```
$reponse = array(
                'csrfName' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
                'csrfHash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
            );
// Your logic

 return $this->output
                            ->set_content_type('application/json')
                            ->set_status_header(200)
                            ->set_output(json_encode(array("regen" => $reponse, "response" => array("status" => $status, "message" => $message))));
```

In the javascript part

```
    var csrfName = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>',
                csrfHash = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';

$.ajax({
                url: __URL__,
                type: "POST",
                data: $form.serialize() + "&" + csrfName + "=" + csrfHash,
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                processData: false,

                success: function (data) {

                    csrfName = data.regen.csrfName;
                    csrfHash = data.regen.csrfHash;

                    if (data.response.status) // if STATUS = TRUE
                    {
                        if (data.response.message === "__WHATEVER__") {
                            // and message === "__WHATEVER__"

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Sorry I don''t follow this. You have used the Security class functions to get csrf name and hash in the controller and then completely independently found them again in the javascript. Why both? Sorry if being dim. Also, the javascript code to use the Security class functions does not work for me in my separate 'script.js' file. It does work if I place all the js between script tags in the view. Can you explain that?

Comment: Well, I placed it in model, and yes this one won't work in external js files. You would need to use a cookie approach for that. Js code get's the token/hash for the request, and the response assigns new one for next request, but as said unless u won't have the js code in your view its not for you / an option might be to disable csrf for specific page at ur config.php - $config['csrf_exclude_uris']

Answer (score 0):

setting `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` to **FALSE** is not a good solution to that problem. What happen during the *AJAX* request is when the request was sent to your controller it will verify for a valid token during the submition. So you need to pass the token name and hashed token so that it will be read as valid.

Here it is...

```
$.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "post",
       data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'},
            success:function() {
                              //do stuff here...
                            }
 });
```